# ¿Cómo recuperar el valor de un select en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo una vista con un select dinamico que carga las clasificaciones que tengo en la base de datos y no sé como acceder al valor del select, solo logro recibir en el controlador, la posición seleccionada y no el value.

Este es el array que paso a la vista:

```
$classifications = Med_classification::all()->pluck('name');
```

Este es el select en la vista:

```
{{ Form::select('classification',$classifications, null, ['required','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Seleccione una clasificación:'])}}
```

Aquí recibo los valores del request en el controlador:
    $request->input('classification');

Cuando imprimo un

```
var_dump($request->input('classification')),
```

solo recibo la posici'on selecionada:

```
string(1) "0"
```

Comment: Debes revisar como esta generado el array `classifications`, este debe tener la estructura de `indice => etiqueta` donde se enviaría solamente el `indice`

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta e incorporé la línea donde obtengo el array classifications que le paso a la vista. No logro ver dónde esta mi error. Espero por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces `pluck` obtienes un array solo con los elementos de esa columna con indices numéricos por ejemplo

```
['Ejemplo 1', 'Ejemplo 2']

//Sus indices quedarían
[0 => 'Ejemplo 1', 1 => 'Ejemplo 2']
```

Para crear un array, puedes recorrerlos con mapWithKeys

```
Med_classification::all()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item->id => $item->name];
})->toArray();
```

Comment: Esa es una vía, gracias, porque me ha servido, pero sigo con la duda de cómo obtener el valor del select, en vez de la posición seleccionada. Espero por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que operación necesitas realizar con el label del select?

Comment: Un formulario en html solo enviará el value de un select

Comment: Necesito recuperar en el controlador el valor la opción seleccionada, en vez de la posición seleccionada. Cuando exploro el request, solo recupero la posición seleccionada en vez, del value.

Answer (score 0):

Hola como estas? Estoy teniendo el mismo problema, cuando recibo el request en el controlador, no me llega el value del select, desconozco si es que me falta agregar algo mas. Estoy usando Laravel 7. Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.